# Check Ubuntu Boot HDD for a MBR virus

Tags: antivirus

Is it possible to check the MBR of the boot drive of Ubuntu for viruses within my Ubuntu?

Is there any good software to do this? I heard ClamAV does not check for MBR viruses.

Comment: Why do you think you  have a virus?

Comment: We live in an unsafe world. If the PC has had Windows on it, it may have MBR infections.

Comment: **Note** *Using Linux is now the preferred method of finding and removing stubborn (MBR, stealth, etc.) malware.  Most of the leading vendors now have a standalone (free) download, that targets Windows malware but is actually using Linux to operate.*

Comment: @UriHerrera I want to check it with a tool/method. You do not know if you do not check. I have several Windows tools which can do that. But I have not Windows installed natively. I did not get any good answer till now.

Answer (score 3):

Based on some internet research:

1) The code of a virus in MBR would be so tiny that it is hard to detect ([1](http://www.murga-linux.com/puppy/viewtopic.php?t=69396)).

2) A reasonable approach would be to compare your MBR before and after an infection. That is what some antivirus do ([2](http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/153060-who-do-i-trust-mbrcheckexe/)).

3) You could copy your MBR to a file with something like `sudo dd if=/dev/sda of=mbr.bin bs=512 count=1` then check the file, which is a binary, with an Hex Editor like [Bless](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/bless).

Comment: ok, this is maybe technical interesting. But I want an automated method to check for MBR virus.

Comment: I believe that there is only two automated ways: one compares your MBR before and after an infection and other compares your MBR with what it is expected to be from a list of defaults MBRs.

Comment: Note that the `dd` command needs to be run from a LiveCD.  If you run it after executing the MBR code, you'll be looking at a pristine MBR served up by the virus disk I/O hook, and not the actual MBR.

Comment: @BenVoigt wow, thx on the info!!

Comment: it only extracts the 1st 512 bytes of the MBR, or is it the full MBR? if so, is the MBR always 512 bytes on every RW media type?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, most viruses / malware actually target Windows/Intel ('Wintel').

So many of the Ubuntu AV solutions mostly look for (and find) Wintel malware.